# How to remove Auth in Laravel (PHP artisan)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

With this command `php artisan make:auth`I got all the **auth** stuffs, but I would like to know how to remove it, or just how to reinitialize.

I've deleted all files, that was created, but when I re-run the command, this doesn't create the mysql user table again

Comment: May be some comments after downvote. Just to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Also upvoted for same reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at the [`make:auth` command source code](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/5.3/Console/MakeAuthCommand.php) to understand what exactly files this command added or changed and revert the changes back.

As you can see, you should remove some views and couple of the controllers.

```
auth/login.blade.php
auth/register.blade.php
auth/passwords/email.blade.php
auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
layouts/app.blade.php
home.blade.php
```

Comment: I've deleted all files, that was created, but when I re-run the command, this doesn't create the mysql user table again.

Comment: @Vixed that's because this command doesn't create any tables. Laravel has `users` table migration out of the box. If you've deleted all tables, delete `migrations` table and run `php artisan migrate` command to create the `users` table again.

Comment: Just done, but still nothing. I tried all I know, but nothing.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` command? What was it's output?

Comment: Looks like you didn't delete `migrations` table.

Comment: Also remove auth directory from app/http/controller

Answer (score 9):

Check the make:auth command's source to understand the files created by it or the changes.

You will need to delete these files

1. auth/login.blade.php
2. auth/register.blade.php
3. auth/passwords/email.blade.php
4. auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
5. layouts/app.blade.php
6. home.blade.php

Once that is done

Go to routes/web.php, delete the routes created by the command make:auth. Remove these two lines and your project will run properly.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Also remove auth directory from app/http/controller

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove user table from database. Also remove migrations entry from migrate tables. 
and than comment route code of auth from `web.php` file in route folder. like

```
Auth::routes();
```

also comment `middleware` from `HomeController __construct()` function.

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Middleware controller and folders? r u serious?

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
resources/views/auth   
resources/views/home.blade.php 
resources/views/layouts
```

(optional, if you don't want it. It won't affect your code)

then delete

```
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/home','HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

then edit the function in HomeController.php to

```
public function index()
{
   return view('welcome');
}
```

for perfection sake 
run `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete 3 files

```
 1. delete dossier auth
 2. layouts/app.blade.php
 3. home.blade.php
```

Answer (score -3):

Just run this code it will fix your issue `php artisan auth:clear-reset`

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
php artisan view:clear
```

this will clear the compiled view for you automatically

Comment: This command will only clear the view caches, nothing related to removing Auth!