# Disable authentication exept some pages | Laravel | Orchid

Tags: php, laravel-10, orchid

sorry for mistakes )

After some discovery, was choosen the shortest way to create form for users requests. IMHO it's Orchid - Laravel Admin Panel

All issues can be resolved exept one. External users have to be able to fill and submit form without login (one route), but for manadgers we have to keep login possibility to acces all routes (screens).

I created a Laravel project as described here https://orchid.software/en/docs/quickstart/

Old solutions ([How to remove Auth in Laravel (PHP artisan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855619/how-to-remove-auth-in-laravel-php-artisan)) not working in Laravel 10 or I'm not understading them.

Comment: And how would you differ between "external user" and "manager" if they do not log in?

Comment: @HonkderHase Users can see the main page and can't see the login rout.
In other words - needed just to disable redirect to the login page. Default dehavior - redirect any request.
Workaroud to make make managers be able to login is simple, I hope.

Comment: Yeah, but until then, "external user" and "manager" are just the same, because the server cannot distinguish between them. The server only sees a request, and if that's the same for any unauthenticated user, the server will treat them...
You need to see it like a server does... there is only a request, nothing else. Any argumentation can only use, what the request sends...

Comment: This is not a problem. No matter which role user have. No login redirection needed for everyone. Auth only for those who have direct link to auth page.